# fadeIn() inside Knockout's afterAdd callback

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-3.4

I am trying to learn the **foreach** binding and I can't understand why the `$(element).fadeIn(500)` line in the code below isn't working:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
        myItems: ko.observableArray([ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]),
        FadeIn: function(element, index, item) {
          if(element.nodeType == 1){
            $(element).fadeIn(500);
          }
        },
        addItem: function() { this.myItems.push('New item'); }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: FadeIn }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
 
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
```

The problem is that when I add a new item, it appears in the page without the **fadeIn** effect.

Codepen -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejxeBr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your element isn't hidden. Change it to

```
$(element).hide().fadeIn(500);
// --------^^^^^^^
```

...or set `style="display: none"` on it in the markup, but that could be a pain because of the pre-existing elements (which won't get `afterAdd` calls).

Example:

```js
var count = 0;
ko.applyBindings({
  myItems: ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']),
  FadeIn: function(element, index, item) {
    if (element.nodeType == 1) {
      $(element).hide().fadeIn(500);
    }
  },
  addItem: function() {
    this.myItems.push('New item');
  }
});
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: FadeIn }">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AnimeshKumar - Good deal! I have to admit I didn't realize `fadeIn` wouldn't do that for you and was surprised your code didn't work, then just did this on a hunch.